# Instagram API : get number of likes and comments

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

After being helped by so many stackoverflow questions, I ask my first question here.

I try to communicate with instagram API with a business instagram account.
I can get the last pics to put them on my website but now i need the number of likes and comments for each pic.

I know that I need an advanced account to get comments and likes of an other account.
But here it is MY pics and MY instagram account.
Do I still need advanced permissions ?

I tried several requests but either i receive the ID of my pics or it says that it's a Bad Request.

I have a standard access everywhere and i can get my pics.

Here is the request i use:

```
$result = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/' . $id . '?fields=like_count,comments_count&access_token=' . $token);
```

I tested with

```
$result = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/' . $id . '?fields=likes.summary(true)&access_token=' . $token);
```

or graph.instagram.com, but i only received a 400 Bad Request.

Is it a problem with permissions or with the request ?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you have access to the media object itself already, then you should not need any extra permissions to get its comment and like count.

Comment: I edited the post with the request that i tested, do you have something that i can test ?